# Octopus : appsettings.json variable substitution 3 level hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-core, octopus-deploy

I am trying to do some json variable substitution from Octopus into my appsettings.json following [link](https://octopus.com/docs/projects/steps/configuration-features/structured-configuration-variables-feature#StructuredConfigurationVariablesFeature-VariableReplacement) everything looks easy till you have 3 level down.

Having this json {"app": {"port": "" }} and octopus' variable app:port eq 8080 converts it to {"app": {"port": 8080}}.

However this doesn't work when you have {"app": {"server" : {"port": "" }}} and octopus' variable app:server:port eq 8080 you get {"app": {"server" : {"port": "" }}}

any idea ?

**UPDATE**

Found the issue: I had some nested variables with period and colons and others with colons,transformation worked fine after I changes all of them to colons.

Comment: A note: In our configuration we use period as delimiter: `app.server.port` and it works very well. The documentation states that colon is to be used: `app:server:post`. I don't know which is correct but period works for us.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen already try app.server.port or app:server:post and also a hybrid mixing period and colons but nothing works for that section, I know that the transformation is happening because app:ConnectionString is applied but the nested server section is ignored.